# kube-router assigning ClusterIPs outside of default subnet

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have in my home lab a default installation of Kubernetes with kube-router as the network provider. kube-router is, as default, set as the service proxy. I have not set an explicit service-cluster-ip-network in my kube-controller-manager, so kube-router should be assigning service cluster IPs only within the default 10.96.x.x/16 subnet. However, I am regularly getting service cluster IPs anywhere within the larger 10.x.x.x./8 subnet. I am at a loss where/why it's not remaining within 10.96.x.x. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell more about your setup? Is it a cluster created with `kubeadm` or `kubespray`? `service-cluster-ip-range` is set in the `kubapi-server`. Could you check what exactly you have configured there? One way to check it is with `$ kubectl cluster-info dump | grep -i "service-cluster-ip-range`

Comment: Debian 10 cluster created with kubeadm. kube-router was installed as the initial CNI plugin immediately after the kubeadm init, no Calico or anything beforehand. I already verified the service-cluster-ip-range as being the default 10.96.0.0/12.

Comment: I reproduced your setup (debian, `kubeadm` with `kube-router`) and couldn't replicate the issue you're having. Could you please add the `kubeadm init` details and content of `kubeadm` config file if used? Could you give some examples of the IP addresses that the service has gotten? Also, please add the parts of `--service-cluster-ip-range` from `kube-controller-manager` and `kubeapi-server`.

Comment: So I managed to reproduce things a bit more "controllably". If `kubeadm` is run without specifying `--service-cidr` in addition to `--pod-network-cidr`, you should be able to reproduce the situation. `kube-controller-manager` and `kubeapi-server` will show the `--service-cluster-ip-range` as being `10.96.0.0/16`, as default. But `kube-router` will be serving out ClusterIPs such as `10.104.5.2`, `10.110.15.13`, etc. If `kubeadm init` is run explicitly with `--service-cidr=10.96.0.0/16`, then ClusterIPs served by `kube-router` properly remain within that subnet range.

Comment: Ran out of space. Explicitly:

`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` will give ClusterIPs such as `10.110.15.13`, etc, even though `kube-controller-manager`'s `--service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/16`.

`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --service-cidr=10.96.0.0/16` properly serves all ClusterIPs from the `10.96.0.0` subnet range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Your Kubernetes cluster is behaving correctly.

**By default (if not specified otherwise) using `kubeadm` to provision your cluster, the `--service-cidr` is set to `10.96.0.0/12`**.

`ClusterIP` address like `10.110.15.13` would be included in the above mentioned network (`10.96.0.0/12`).

I've provided more explanation below:

---

#### Subnetting

If you use one of the available online [IP calculators](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.96.0.0&mask1=12&mask2=) you will be seeing exact same situation like the one included below:

| CIDR | 10.96.0.0/12 |
| --- | --- |
| Subnet mask | 255.240.0.0 |
| Network address (first) | 10.96.0.0 |
| Broadcast address (last) | 10.111.255.255 |
| First useable address | **10.96.0.1** |
| Last useable address | **10.111.255.254** |
| Number of hosts allocatable | 1048574 |

By above diagram you can see that the `Service IP` range would be following:

- `10.96.0.1`-`10.111.255.254`

This would make IP's like: `10.104.5.2`, `10.110.15.13` **be in range** of above network.

---

#### Kubernetes `--service-cidr`

As said earlier if you don't specify the `--service-cidr` when using `$ kubeadm init` it will be set to default `10.96.0.0/12`.

Following the official documentation of `kubeadm`:

> ```sh
> --service-cidr string     Default: "10.96.0.0/12"
> Use alternative range of IP address for service VIPs.
> ```
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Setup tools: Kubeadm: Kubeadm init: Options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#options)*

If you provision the cluster without this parameter, you will be able to see it configured in the:

- `kube-apiserver`:

```sh
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system   kube-apiserver-kubernetes-NODE_NAME -o yaml | grep "service-cluster-ip-range" 
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
```

- `kube-controller-manager`

```sh
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kubernetes-NODE_NAME -o yaml | grep "service-cluster-ip-range" 
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
```

---

#### Kube-router

It's also explicitly stated in the `kube-router`'s source code:

> ```golang
> func NewKubeRouterConfig() *KubeRouterConfig {
>   return &KubeRouterConfig{
>       // SKIPPED 
>       ClusterIPCIDR:                  "10.96.0.0/12",
>        // SKIPPED
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> -- *[Github.com: Cloudnativelabds: Kube-router: Pkg: Options: Options.go: Line 73](https://github.com/cloudnativelabs/kube-router/blob/c14588535433e3c334fa4dd639168619f9a34210/pkg/options/options.go#L73)*

> ```golang
>   fs.StringVar(&s.ClusterIPCIDR, "service-cluster-ip-range", s.ClusterIPCIDR,
>       "CIDR value from which service cluster IPs are assigned. Default: 10.96.0.0/12")
> ```
>
> -- *[Github.com: Cloudnativelabds: Kube-router: Pkg: Options: Options.go: Line 187](https://github.com/cloudnativelabs/kube-router/blob/c14588535433e3c334fa4dd639168619f9a34210/pkg/options/options.go#L187)*

It's also referenced in the [user guide](https://github.com/cloudnativelabs/kube-router/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md).

Comment: *sigh*. Embarrassed, I am. I am so used to thinking in Class B terms I kept (for some stupid reason) mentally reading /12 as /16.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I was able to find the file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` on the master node and correct the `service-cluster-ip-range` line.

In my case, it appears that a kubeadm command to install the descheduler modified the line.